# WPF UI Design Question: How to represent data in a structured way from a single complex object

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

WPF noob here...

I would like some advice around how I could present data to a user in a structured, easy to understand way. My data is coming from a large JSON string that gets parsed into a single object that is reasonably complex. The object consists largely of a variety of individual strings and arrays that is structured in a fairly hierarchical pattern.

Here is a flavour of what I'm working with (note the nested []s keeps going on for a few more layers):

```
public class MyBigFatModel
{
    [JsonProperty("pattern")]
    public Pattern pattern { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fingerprint")]
    public string Fingerprint { get; set; }

    public partial class Pattern
    {
        [JsonProperty("uuid")]
        public string Uuid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("created")]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("modified")]
        public object Modified { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("info")]
        public Info Info { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("holeTemplates")]
        public HoleTemplate[] HoleTemplates { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thingy")]
        public Thingy Thingy { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Thingy
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thingyW")]
        public ThingyW ThingyW { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("encoder")]
        public Encoder Encoder { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("customer")]
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty("location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("comment")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ThingyW
    {
        [JsonProperty("NameDesc1")]
        public string NameDesc1 { get; set; }
                    
        [JsonProperty("NameDesc2")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long BNameDesc2 { get; set; }

        ...

        [JsonProperty("serialNo")]
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("battLevel")]
        public long BattLevel { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fileUUID")]
        public string FileUuid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("pcUUID")]
        public string PcUuid { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Encoder
    {
        [JsonProperty("line1")]
        public string Line1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("line2")]
        public string Line2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("serialNo")]
        public object SerialNo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("battLevel")]
        public long BattLevel { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("state")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expiry")]
        public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("validationKey")]
        public string ValidationKey { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("standoffSeconds")]
        public long StandoffSeconds { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("beaconID")]
        public string BeaconId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("aTime")]
        public DateTime ATime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fTime")]
        public DateTime FTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("codes")]
        public Code[] Codes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("holes")]
        public Hole[] Holes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("availableUID")]
        public string[] AvailableUid { get; set; }
    }
```

Initially I wanted to use a TreeView but as far as I can see it only binds to a collection not an individual object.

Any suggestions around how I might represent this data in a hierarchical fashion that will allow a user to drill into the data?

I'm still open to using Treeview but my limited understanding would lead me to think that I'd need to pull the object apart and create a bunch of new collections I can point the tree to.

Any ideas, advice etc would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Treeview is what you want, but you need some modifications to fit your needs. See [this example](https://michaelscodingspot.com/displaying-any-net-object-in-a-wpf-treeview/)

Comment: I agree, treeview is the most user-friendly UI element for deeply nested objects.  If you're worried about only having a single item and the treeview taking a collection, just wrap your one item in an array `new[] { myItem }`.

Comment: Depends how you want your data displayed exactly. You might not need to manipulate it much at all. Just define hierarchical data templates and data templates. Btw you can deserialise Json ignoring case of properties.